# Missing PHP53 or PHP54 from homebrew-php

Tags: php, composer-php, homebrew

With this command

```
$ brew install josegonzalez/php/composer
```

I get this message

```
Missing PHP53 or PHP54 from homebrew-php. Please install one or the other before continuing
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

I have MacOsX 10.7 with MAMP. Can someone help me?

Comment: what version of PHP are you running?

Comment: Php version is 5.3 but I've configured MAMP to 5.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you seeing this warning?

> Warning: No developer tools installed.
>   
> Install the Command Line Tools:
>     xcode-select --install

If so, it might fix your issue:

```
xcode-select --install
brew install php55
brew install composer
```

It worked for me. Warning, the xcode-select install takes a long time.

Answer (score 17):

If you have already php installed, you can ignore the dependencies by `--ignore-dependencies` parameter in example:

```
brew install composer --ignore-dependencies
```

Or if you don't have php, you'll have to install first via:

```
brew install php55
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The homebrew recipe really ought to check if PHP is already installed before saying you need to install it...!

Comment: You sire, need more upvotes for --ignore-dependencies

Comment: What if there are other dependencies that need to be satisfied?

Answer (score 8):

I use OSX 10.9 and use XAMPP.

I also have this problem.

But I use brew install php, and then install composer successfully.

```
brew install php54
```

---

**update**

or

```
brew install php55
```

Comment: Or: `brew install php55`.

Comment: Same problem here. If you get stuck with permissions when you try to 'brew link libpng xz freetype', follow this thread: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/9953

Comment: On 10.11 El Capitan, I did not have this problem. I simply had to --ignore-dependencies and it installed Composer just fine without reinstalling PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when doing `brew intsall php-cs-fixer` I upgraded PHP from 5.4.14 to 5.4.16 via Homebrew (maybe try reinstalling if you are already up-to-date) and removed multiple paths to PHP in my PATH Environment variable. Not sure which bit fixed it for me, but it now works correctly.

Also I was advised to try `brew install --env-std php-cs-fixer` in the Homebrew IRC channel, it did not work for me, but might do for others.

Hope that helps anyone with the same issue!

Answer (score -1):

I get the same problem with brew, I suggest to install it manually with:

```
$ curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

$ php composer.phar
```

Comment: Is not composer stuff, but homebrew stuff.